# Double zsh prompt is showing unformatted then formatted

Tags: zsh, macos, oh-my-zsh, iterm2

Any command I run (aside from `clear`) results in a double zsh prompt -- the first one showing the unformatted prompt, the second one showing the correct, formatted prompt.

[image]

My `~/.zshrc` file:

```
if [[ -r "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh" ]]; then
  source "${XDG_CACHE_HOME:-$HOME/.cache}/p10k-instant-prompt-${(%):-%n}.zsh"
fi

export ZSH="$HOME/.oh-my-zsh"

ZSH_THEME="agnoster"

 zstyle ':omz:update' mode auto      # update automatically without asking


  ENABLE_CORRECTION="true"

  COMPLETION_WAITING_DOTS="%F{yellow}waiting...%f"


 HIST_STAMPS="mm/dd/yyyy"

plugins=(
  zsh-completions
  git
  pip
  jsontools
  dotenv
)

source ~/powerlevel10k/powerlevel10k.zsh-theme

# To customize prompt, run `p10k configure` or edit ~/.p10k.zsh.
[[ ! -f ~/.p10k.zsh ]] || source ~/.p10k.zsh


[ -f ~/.fzf.zsh ] && source ~/.fzf.zsh

export FZF_DEFAULT_OPTS='-height=40% -preview="cat {}" -preview-window=right:60%:wrap'

alias ip="ipconfig getifaddr en0"
alias zshconf="vim ~/.zshrc"
alias szsh="source ~/.zshrc"
alias ohmyzsh="cd ~/.oh-my-zsh"
alias gs="git status"
alias gac="git add . && git commit -am"
alias gb="git branch --show-current"
alias goof="git add --all && git commit --amend --no-edit"
alias ff="find . | grep "
alias ft="grep -lrni -e "
alias rando="openssl rand -base64 24"

fpath+=${ZSH_CUSTOM:-${ZSH:-~/.oh-my-zsh}/custom}/plugins/zsh-completions/src
source ~/.zsh/zsh-autosuggestions/zsh-autosuggestions.zsh


source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh

[[ -s "/Users/<user>/.gvm/scripts/gvm" ]] && source "/Users/<user>/.gvm/scripts/gvm"
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks!

Output from command: `typeset -p PS1 RPS1; typeset -fp precmd preexec $precmd_functions $preexec_functions`

```
typeset PS1=$'${$((_p9k_on_expand()))+}%{${_p9k__raw_msg-}${_p9k__raw_msg::=}%}${(e)_p9k_t[7]}${_p9k__1-${${:-${_p9k__d::=0}${_p9k__rprompt::=${_p9k__1r-${${:-${_p9k__bg::=NONE}${_p9k__i::=0}${_p9k__sss::=${(Q)${:-"%\\\\{%\\\\}"}}}}+}${${:-"${${(%):-%j}:#0}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=""}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=12}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(000|000)}:+14}}${_p9k__n:=15}${_p9k__v::=}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_CONTENT}"}${_p9k__c::=${_p9k__c//\C-M}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rbackground_jobs+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}1}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__c}%b%K{000\\}%F{006\\}${${(M)_p9k__e:#11}:+ }$_p9k__v${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%K{000\\}%F{006\\} %b%K{000\\}%F{006\\}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%K{000\\}%F{006\\} %k%F{000\\}%b%K{000\\}%F{006\\}}${_p9k__i::=3}${_p9k__bg::=000}}+}}}${${:-"${${:-$_p9k__keymap.$_p9k__zle_state}:#(vicmd.*|vivis.*|vivli.*|*.*insert*)}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=OVERTYPE}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=28}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(003|003)}:+30}}${_p9k__n:=31}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_CONTENT}"}${_p9k__c::=${_p9k__c//\C-M}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rvi_mode+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__c}%b%K{003\\}%F{000\\}${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%K{003\\}%F{000\\} %b%K{003\\}%F{000\\}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%K{003\\}%F{000\\} %k%F{003\\}%b%K{003\\}%F{000\\}}${_p9k__i::=41}${_p9k__bg::=003}}+}}}${${:-"${(M)${:-$_p9k__keymap$_p9k__region_active}:#vicmd0}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=NORMAL}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=32}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(002|002)}:+34}}${_p9k__n:=35}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_CONTENT}"}${_p9k__c::=${_p9k__c//\C-M}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rvi_mode+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__c}%b%K{002\\}%F{000\\}${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%K{002\\}%F{000\\} %b%K{002\\}%F{000\\}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%K{002\\}%F{000\\} %k%F{002\\}%b%K{002\\}%F{000\\}}${_p9k__i::=41}${_p9k__bg::=002}}+}}}${${:-"${(M)${:-$_p9k__keymap$_p9k__region_active}:#(vicmd1|vivis?|vivli?)}"}:+${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=VISUAL}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=36}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(004|004)}:+38}}${_p9k__n:=39}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_CONTENT}"}${_p9k__c::=${_p9k__c//\C-M}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rvi_mode+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}${_p9k__c}%b%K{004\\}%F{000\\}${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%K{004\\}%F{000\\} %b%K{004\\}%F{000\\}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%K{004\\}%F{000\\} %k%F{004\\}%b%K{004\\}%F{000\\}}${_p9k__i::=41}${_p9k__bg::=004}}+}}}${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=08:53:09 AM}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=40}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x$_p9k__bg}:#x(007|007)}:+42}}${_p9k__n:=43}${_p9k__v::=}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_CONTENT}"}${_p9k__c::=${_p9k__c//\C-M}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1rtime+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}1}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__w>/$_p9k__w}at ${_p9k__c}%b%K{007\\}%F{000\\}${${(M)_p9k__e:#11}:+ }$_p9k__v${${:-${_p9k__w::=%b%K{007\\}%F{000\\} %b%K{007\\}%F{000\\}}${_p9k__sss::=%b%K{007\\}%F{000\\} %k%F{007\\}%b%K{007\\}%F{000\\}}${_p9k__i::=46}${_p9k__bg::=007}}+}}$_p9k__sss%b%k%f}}${_p9k__lprompt::=${_p9k__1l_frame-"%240F╭─"}${_p9k__1l-${${:-${_p9k__bg::=NONE}${_p9k__i::=0}${_p9k__sss::=%f}}+}${${:-${P9K_CONTENT::=}${_p9k__n::=}${${${_p9k__bg:-0}:#NONE}:-${_p9k__n::=44}}${_p9k__n:=${${(M)${:-x007}:#x($_p9k__bg|${_p9k__bg:-0})}:+46}}${_p9k__n:=47}${_p9k__c::="${P9K_CONTENT}"}${_p9k__c::=${_p9k__c//\C-M}}${_p9k__e::=${${_p9k__1los_icon+00}:-${${(%):-$_p9k__c%1(l.1.0)}[-1]}0}}}+}${${_p9k__e:#00}:+${${_p9k_t[$_p9k__n]/<_p9k__ss>/$_p9k__ss}/<_p9k__s>/$_p9k__s}${_p9k__c}%b%K{007\\}%F{232\\} ${${:-${_p9k__s::=%F{007\\}}${_p9k__ss::=}${_p9k__sss::=%F{007\\}}${_p9k__i::=1}${_p9k__bg::=007}}+}}${(e)_p9k__vcs}%b%k$_p9k__sss%b%k%f}}}+}${(e)_p9k_t[6]}${_p9k__lprompt}${${_p9k__g+\n}:-${:-"%F{240}"}${${${_p9k__m:#-*}:+${${_p9k__1g+${(pl.$((_p9k__m+1)).. .)}}:-${(pl.$((_p9k__m+1))..─.)}}$_p9k__rprompt${_p9k_t[$((1+!_p9k__ind))]}}:-\n}%b%k%f}}${_p9k__2-${_p9k__2l_frame-"%240F╰─"}${_p9k__2l-${${:-${_p9k__bg::=NONE}${_p9k__i::=0}${_p9k__sss::=%f}}+}%b%k$_p9k__sss%b%k%f${:-" %b%k%f"}}}${${COLUMNS::=$_p9k__clm}+}'
_p9k_do_nothing () {
    true
}
_zsh_autosuggest_start () {
    if (( ${+ZSH_AUTOSUGGEST_MANUAL_REBIND} ))
    then
        add-zsh-hook -d precmd _zsh_autosuggest_start
    fi
    _zsh_autosuggest_bind_widgets
}
omz_termsupport_precmd () {
    [[ "${DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE:-}" != true ]] || return
    title "$ZSH_THEME_TERM_TAB_TITLE_IDLE" "$ZSH_THEME_TERM_TITLE_IDLE"
}
omz_termsupport_cwd () {
    local URL_HOST URL_PATH
    URL_HOST="$(omz_urlencode -P $HOST)"  || return 1
    URL_PATH="$(omz_urlencode -P $PWD)"  || return 1
    [[ -z "$KONSOLE_VERSION" ]] || URL_HOST=""
    printf "\e]7;file://%s%s\e\\" "${URL_HOST}" "${URL_PATH}"
}
_p9k_precmd () {
    __p9k_new_status=$?
    __p9k_new_pipestatus=($pipestatus)
    trap ":" INT
    [[ -o ksh_arrays ]] && __p9k_ksh_arrays=1  || __p9k_ksh_arrays=0
    [[ -o sh_glob ]] && __p9k_sh_glob=1  || __p9k_sh_glob=0
    _p9k_restore_special_params
    _p9k_precmd_impl
    [[ ${+__p9k_instant_prompt_active} == 0 || -o no_prompt_cr ]] || __p9k_instant_prompt_active=2
    setopt no_local_options no_prompt_bang prompt_percent prompt_subst prompt_cr prompt_sp
    typeset -g __p9k_trapint='_p9k_trapint; return 130'
    trap "$__p9k_trapint" INT
    : ${(%):-%b%k%s%u}
}
_p9k_preexec1 () {
    _p9k_restore_special_params
    unset __p9k_trapint
    trap - INT
}
omz_termsupport_preexec () {
    [[ "${DISABLE_AUTO_TITLE:-}" != true ]] || return
    emulate -L zsh
    setopt extended_glob
    local -a cmdargs
    cmdargs=("${(z)2}")
    if [[ "${cmdargs[1]}" = fg ]]
    then
        local job_id jobspec="${cmdargs[2]#%}"
        case "$jobspec" in
            (<->) job_id=${jobspec}  ;;
            ("" | % | +) job_id=${(k)jobstates[(r)*:+:*]}  ;;
            (-) job_id=${(k)jobstates[(r)*:-:*]}  ;;
            ([?]*) job_id=${(k)jobtexts[(r)*${(Q)jobspec}*]}  ;;
            (*) job_id=${(k)jobtexts[(r)${(Q)jobspec}*]}  ;;
        esac
        if [[ -n "${jobtexts[$job_id]}" ]]
        then
            1="${jobtexts[$job_id]}"
            2="${jobtexts[$job_id]}"
        fi
    fi
    local CMD="${1[(wr)^(*=*|sudo|ssh|mosh|rake|-*)]:gs/%/%%}"
    local LINE="${2:gs/%/%%}"
    title "$CMD" "%100>...>${LINE}%<<"
}
_p9k_preexec2 () {
    typeset -g _p9k__preexec_cmd=$2
    _p9k__timer_start=EPOCHREALTIME
    P9K_TTY=old
    (( ! $+_p9k__iterm_cmd )) || _p9k_iterm2_preexec
}
```

Comment: And if you remove oh-my-zsh?

Comment: Can you show the output of `typeset -p PS1 RPS1; typeset -fp precmd preexec $precmd_functions $preexec_functions`?

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas, I've added the output to my original question. Thank you

Comment: Ouch, that's heavy. Those in turn call more functions that we don't see here which might be the ones outputting that raw prompt. You'll probably have to debug it on you own. You could `set -o xtrace` to try and see what outputs it.

Comment: Thanks for the help @StéphaneChazelas. Once I commented out the following line from my `~/.zshrc` file and quit and reopened iTerm2 the prompt was back to normal. Not sure what's happening, but it appears related to oh-my-zsh
`source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out `source $ZSH/oh-my-zsh.sh` in the `~/.zshrc` was causing some issues with Powerlevel10k. Commented this line out and the prompt went back to normal after quitting iTerm2 and opening it back up.